# MS Access: Images disappear when reopening

Tags: ms-access

I have this very simple table in Microsoft Access:
[image: Fields: ID (number), FullName (text), Glasses (yes/no)]

And this form:

[image: Image of glasses when 'glasses' field is yes, image of no glasses when 'glasses' field is no]

The image next to each record changes based on the "Glasses" field automatically, so when "Glasses" is true, there is an image of glasses, and when it is false, there is an image of a person.

I have two images in my Image gallery: **glasses.jpg** and **noglasses.jpg**

[image: "glasses", "noglasses"]

And my image source is set to:

```
=IIf([Glasses],"glasses.jpg","noglasses.jpg")
```

As you can see this is all working great. The problem starts when I'm fully exiting then reopening my project in Microsoft Access: All of the images just disappear.

[image: No images!]

I was wondering if there is any way to fix that.

I did find a way to make them appear again but it require an action every time I open the database:

1. By going to the form design
2. clicking "insert image" (for some reason all of the images are there)
3. right-clicking an image (does not matter which image)
4. Clicking "Update"
5. Selecting the image again from the files explorer
6. Opening the form again

Comment: I have never used Image Gallery for dynamic display of images. I suspect you need to either embed images in Attachment field of an Images table and use JOIN in query or DLookup() to pull from table or reference external file path location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, setting the image type to "shared" and changing the image source to:

```
=IIf([Glasses],"glasses","noglasses")
```

Solved the issue